# Web scraping worked fine in IE 9 but breaks in IE 11

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I had a procedure that scraped information from a website in IE9 however after updating to IE11 the procedure breaks when trying to enter a piece of data into 
an input box on the webpage.  The code recognizes the field and it is listed as on object when I debug but when I try to enter a value into the box using CUSIP.value it does not enter anything on the webpage.  I think it has something to do with the source being updated after the browser was updated.  I could have sworn that the identifier for "txtCusipNo" in the HTML was listed as an ID instead of a Name.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

**HTML from website**

```
<td class="tbl1">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="txtCusipNo" VALUE="" CLASS="input" SIZE="11" MAXLENGTH="9">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('/SecFinderII1/SIM_SeekSearch.jsp?clientobjectreference=frmSearchEntry.txtCusipNo&formname=frmSearchEntry&textboxname=txtCusipNo','SecurityFinder','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no');"><img src="/RDPANN/pbs/images/lookup.gif" border="0" alt="Open Security Finder" align="absmiddle"></a>&nbsp;<IMG NAME="txtCusipIMG"SRC="/RDPANN/pbs/images/req.gif" ALIGN="ABSMIDDLE">
</td>
```

**VBA code**

```
Private Sub EnterCUSIP()
Retry:
Set CUSIP = Doc.getElementById("txtCusipNo")
Err.Clear
valA = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1)
On Error Resume Next
CUSIP.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1) 'insert CUSIP
If Err.Number = 91 Then GoTo Retry
Set CurrentWindow = IE.document.parentWindow
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("javascript:processForm(document.forms.frmSearchEntry)")  'Search (hit enter)
If Err.Number = -2147352319 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE):DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect that the HTML source has been changed and may make unannounced changes in the future, I would recommend switching to the ie.Document.All.Item property.

```
Doc.all.Item("txtCusipNo").Value = 123
```

The `.Item` identifier can be either an ID or a Name, there is no distinction between the two. However, I would be concerned that the identifying factor (e.g. *txtCusipNo*) may not be unique on that page. Yes, it is *supposed* to be but a growing number of HTML developers are using code like `divs(0).getElementById("txtCusipNo")` and `divs(1).getElementById("txtCusipNo")`.